# How to assign css class of day1 to every non-empty input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Can someone explain me how to assign a local CSS definition for this function day1? and
how to assign css class to every non-empty input field?

I have already tried the code below

```
function day1(){
  $currentDayColor = 'blue';
     document.getElementById('dayone').value = Date();
     $('input:not(:disabled):not([readonly])').each(function() {
     if (($(this).val() == "") || ($(this).val) == " ") 
       {
           $(this).css('color', 'blue');

       }
     if (($(this).val() !== "") && ($(this).val) !== " ") {$(this).addClass('classPreviousValue2');}

});
    $('select:not(:disabled):not([readonly])').each(function() {
    if (($(this).val() == "") || ($(this).val) == " ") {$(this).css('color', 'blue');}
   if (($(this).val() !== "") && ($(this).val) !== " ") {$(this).addClass('classPreviousValue2');}
});
}
```

How to assign the CSS class to every non-empty input field.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and CSS as well. Also, do you need this done all at once or can it happen as each field gets/loses data?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do is to add a `change` event callback to each `input` and in the callback, test the value and apply or remove the class as needed.

```js
// Set up a change event handler for all the inputs
$("input.styledByValue").on("change", function(){
  $(this).val() === "" ? $(this).addClass("hasNoValue") : $(this).removeClass("hasNoValue");
});
```

```css
.hasNoValue { border:2px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Field: <input class="styledByValue"><br>
Field: <input class="styledByValue"><br>
Field: <input class="styledByValue"><br>
Field: <input class="styledByValue"><br>
Field: <input class="styledByValue"><br>
Field: <input class="styledByValue"><br>
```

If you need all the fields checked at once and at a specific time, the same code needs to be altered by adding a loop.

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  // Loop over all the inputs
  $("input.styledByValue").each(function(){
    $(this).val() === "" ? $(this).addClass("hasNoValue") : $(this).removeClass("hasNoValue");
  });
});
```

```css
.hasNoValue { border:2px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Field: <input class="styledByValue"><br>
Field: <input class="styledByValue"><br>
Field: <input class="styledByValue"><br>
Field: <input class="styledByValue"><br>
Field: <input class="styledByValue"><br>
Field: <input class="styledByValue"><br>
<button>Check Fields</button>
```

Comment: Could also possibly do `$(this).toggleClass('hasNoValue', this.value === '')`

Comment: How can i have a local CSS Definition in the function Day 1?

Comment: @Z7272727 You don't put CSS definitions inside of JavaScript. You can either set an inline style (not recommended) or add/remove classes that have been defined in a stylesheet somewhere.

Comment: I want that when the use click the button and that button execute the function day1 it should assign css class to every non-empty input field. and then on save, remove the css class from every empty input field.

Comment: @Z7272727 Have you read my answer? The second example shows how to do this.

Comment: Thank you if was great help